# PHP: Convert input value result to string

Tags: php

if it possible to make variable from text input?

```
$price = 10;
$shipping ="<input type=\"text\" id=\"shipping\" value=\"$row[price]\">";  <---- sring?
```

and display to new variable:

```
$total = $price+$shipping;
```

Comment: Do you want to extract $row['price'] from the string or append <input ... /> to the total variable?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do? Can you elaborate and add more code?

Comment: Why the new question? We addressed this issue already over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486205/php-onchange-option-select-update-total It has nothing to with data type conversion and all to do with PHP execution having terminated before the JS is even executed.

Comment: At this point, it's obvious the OP should RTFM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line of code makes no sense.

You'll need to do

```
$total = $row['price'] + $shipping; //assuming you actually have numericals in here
```

Also, you might want to just use `'` (single quote) to make your html input

```
$shipping ="<input type='text' id='shipping' value='{$row['price']}'>";
```

Less escaping involved and PHP variables are more visible. This is just a suggestion and owed more to personal preference, of course :)

Comment: see my comment on the question above to alleviate your confusion over the OPs question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the shipping cost is not being passed here.
You are assigning a string to "shipping" that is actually html.

What you should be doing is

```
<html>
  <form>
  <input type="text" name="cost" value="10" /> //this should not be entered by the user
  <select name="shipping"> // choose a shipping method
    <option value="1.99">$1.99</option>
    <option value="10.99">$10.99</option>
    <option value="109.90">$109.90</option>
  </select>
  </form>
</html>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['cost']) && isset($_POST['shipping'])) {
    $grand_total = $_POST['cost'] + $_POST['shipping']);
  }
?>
```

You don't need to cast anything here because PHP is pretty good at figuring out what you want.  It will convert your strings to floats or ints to do the calculation and assign it to $grand_total